# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder

Tags: java, soap, jboss, jax-ws

I'm using JBoss 4 with Java 6u29. I generated some classes for a soap webservice with wsimport. Everything works fine except for one thing.

Whenever the webservice responds with a soap fault I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder
```

The class is included in the JRE. I have no idea why this class isn't found. I searched on google but wasn't successfull. Do you have any idea what could cause this error?

Comment: Look for a related thread at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494738/catching-webservice-exception-with-cxf-noclassdeffounderror-soapfaultbuilder

Comment: That thread is about CXF. I'm not using it. I'm using the reference implementation that comes with Java 6. So there is no need to add any dependencies, right? The class is in the rt.jar which I assume is always loaded.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem. Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: No, we updated to Wildfly 8.2.

Comment: Try to give a try at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13036954/1346996) answer.